# PDFBox 2 - How do I remove borders from form fields before flattening?

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

I am using a PDF document as a template, with a form in it, and after I put the values into the form I would like to remove the field borders, before flattening the form. The borders are useful while editing, but they are horrible when the form is "rendered". I cannot change the colour of the borders to the background colour as it's not uniform.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is modified from the [AddBorderToField.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/AddBorderToField.java?view=markup) example from the source code download:

```
PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0); // only the first widget for simplicity
PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics = widget.getAppearanceCharacteristics();
if (appearanceCharacteristics == null)
{
     // if it doesn't exist, create it
     appearanceCharacteristics = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
}
appearanceCharacteristics.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[]{}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE)); // empty array = invisible color
widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearanceCharacteristics);
acroForm.refreshAppearances(); // alternatively, set the value of the field
```

Comment: No, it does not appear to work, the borders are still there.

Comment: Please link to your Pdf and tell the name of the field. I tested my code on the PDF generated by the CreateSimpleForm example in the source code download. Also tell how you got to all the fields (there's a pitfall there, using `acroform.getFields()` without reading the javadoc).

Comment: @Bruno if this code does not work, the borders might not be part of the actual field but instead a rectangle in the page content and merely positioned so that this rectangle appears to be the field border. To remove such "borders" would require code specially tailored for your pdf.

Comment: Here're the files: java [code](http://www.files.com/shared/5a035e4b8d473/Test.java.zip) (zipped)
and [pdf](http://www.files.com/shared/5a035e4b725a9/test.pdf)

Comment: It is like mkl wrote. You have an extra rectangle in the page content stream.

Comment: The posted Code in incomplete (what is fieldAppearance?) and the zippped and PDF version is not available anymore. Please include all the code in you post on stackoverflow.